# System Center Configuration Manger 2012 SP1 PXE boot

Tags: pxe-boot, sccm, wds, system-center, sccm-2012

I am trying to set up my System Center Configuration manager server to be a PXE server for client deployments but I am having no luck in getting it to work.  It seems to bypass SCCM and boot right from WDS.  I get a Windows 8 style blue screen saying:

"The Boot Configuration Data (BCD) file from the PXE server does not contain a valid operating system entry (error 0x0000098)."

I have pxe boot enabled on the distribution point and boot images.  I have a Windows 8 image in SCCM.  I have a boundary group set up.  All the boot images and OS images are deployed to the DP.  Can anyone think of something I'm missing?

Comment: Did you boot into WinPE on the client machine and format and reparition the machine?

Comment: Does it appear that the client is actually downloading the bcd file, or is it just failing out?

Answer (score 1):

After deploying your boot image, operating system image and your task sequence, as mentioned by MDMoore313, you have to wait for a short period of time before you can do a PXE boot of your boot image *and* launch your tak sequence.

One way to check if your deployment is complete is to head to Monitoring, then Distribution Status and Content Status. Double-click on the image you're deploying and ensure the deployment status is green.

Answer (score 0):

It's not actually bypassing sccm, this is how sccm deploys it's boot.wim (using WDS). If you're using SCCM 2012 **not** SP1, then you cannot deploy Windows 8 with it. If you are using SP1, then make sure that the boot wims your using are the boot wims that came with SP1. Also, make sure the boot wim you set for deployment is x86, it's a matter of preference really, but at least the x86 boot wim will deploy x86 and x64 architectures.

Finally, it's possible that the boot wims weren't deployed to the distribution point correctly (happens more than one might think). Try updating the DPs, and giving it another try.